# search value from array of dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have `NSMutableArray` of dictionaries:
something like :

```
(
{
    "Key1" = "Name1";
    "Key2" = "Age1";
    "Key3" = "Address1";
 },
{
    "Key1" = "Name2";
    "Key2" = "Age2";
    "Key3" = "Address2";
},
{
    "Key1" = "Name3";
    "Key2" = "Age3";
    "Key3" = "Address3";
}
)
```

Using this code to search key 1 value.
User can type even alphabet and I have to search the all the dictionary with key containing that alphabet.

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"'Key1' =[cd] %@", searchstring];
NSArray *filteredContacts = [DisplayArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

But this predicate is not working. please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try and check using below code.

Use `contains[c]` in `NSPredicate` like below:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Key1 contains[c] %@ ",searchstring];
NSArray *filteredContacts = [DisplayArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```